# Given a decision network, compute the EU of buying a book

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, bayesian-network

I am given this homework:

[image: homework]

And this is what I have done up to now:

**(a)** This is the decision network for that problem

[image: net]

While I think the decision network is correct, I am having struggles with part **(b)**.

Firstly I have computed the utilities based on the action $b$ (buy/not buy the book) and the (values of) random variable $p$ (Passes) this way:

- If the student buys the book and passes the course, then the utility is $-100+2000 = 1900$ (i.e., $u(b,p) = 1900$)
- If the student buys the book but does not pass the course, then the utility is $-100+0 = -100$ (i.e., $u(b,\neg p) = -100$)
- If the student does not buy the book but passes the course, then the utility is $0+2000 = 2000$ (i.e., $u(\neg b,p) = 2000$)
- If the student does not buy the book and does not pass the course, then the utility is $0+0 = 0$ (i.e., $u(\neg b,\neg p) = 0$)

Now I have to compute the expected utility of buying the book (and of not buying it), that is:

\begin{align}
EU(b) & = \sum_p P(p|b) u(b,p) \\
& = 1900 \times \sum_p P(p|b)
\end{align}

How do I compute $P(p|b)$? My idea is
$$
P(p|b) \propto P(p,b) = \sum_M P(p,b,M)
$$
where
$$
P(p,b,M) = P(p|M) P(b) P(M|b) = P(p|M) P(M,b)
$$
but the exercise won't give me that information.

Comment: This belongs [here](https://economics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Snoop Are you really sure?

Comment: I associate utility theory with economics so yes, imo

Comment: @Snoop Artificial Intelligence and Mathematics as well.